# Extending JavaScript's Date.parse to allow for DD/MM/YYYY (non-US formatted dates)?

Tags: javascript

I've come up with this solution to extending JavaScript's `Date.parse` function to allow for dates formatted in DD/MM/YYYY (rather then the American standard [and default] MM/DD/YYYY):

```
(function() {
    var fDateParse = Date.parse;

    Date.parse = function(sDateString) {
        var a_sLanguage = ['en','en-us'],
            a_sMatches = null,
            sCurrentLanguage,
            dReturn = null,
            i
        ;

            //#### Traverse the a_sLanguages (as reported by the browser)
        for (i = 0; i < a_sLanguage.length; i++) {
                //#### Collect the .toLowerCase'd sCurrentLanguage for this loop
            sCurrentLanguage = (a_sLanguage[i] + '').toLowerCase();

                //#### If this is the first English definition
            if (sCurrentLanguage.indexOf('en') == 0) {
                    //#### If this is a definition for a non-American based English (meaning dates are "DD MM YYYY")
                if (sCurrentLanguage.indexOf('en-us') == -1 &&      // en-us = English (United States) + Palau, Micronesia
                    sCurrentLanguage.indexOf('en-ca') == -1 &&      // en-ca = English (Canada)
                    sCurrentLanguage.indexOf('en-ph') == -1 &&      // en-ph = English (Philippians)
                    sCurrentLanguage.indexOf('en-bz') == -1         // en-bz = English (Belize)
                ) {
                        //#### Setup a oRegEx to locate "## ## ####" (allowing for any sort of delimiter except a '\n') then collect the a_sMatches from the passed sDateString
                    var oRegEx = new RegExp("(([0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1})[^0-9]*?([0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1})[^0-9]*?([0-9]{4}))", "i");
                    a_sMatches = oRegEx.exec(sDateString);
                }

                    //#### Fall from the loop (as we've found the first English definition)
                break;
            }
        }

            //#### If we were able to find a_sMatches for a non-American English "DD MM YYYY" formatted date
        if (a_sMatches != null) {
            var oRegEx = new RegExp(a_sMatches[0], "i");
                //#### .parse the sDateString via the normal Date.parse function, but replacing the "DD?MM?YYYY" with "YYYY/MM/DD" beforehand
                //####     NOTE: a_sMatches[0]=[Default]; a_sMatches[1]=DD?MM?YYYY; a_sMatches[2]=DD; a_sMatches[3]=MM; a_sMatches[4]=YYYY
            dReturn = fDateParse(sDateString.replace(oRegEx, a_sMatches[4] + "/" + a_sMatches[3] + "/" + a_sMatches[2]));
        }
            //#### Else .parse the sDateString via the normal Date.parse function
        else {
            dReturn = fDateParse(sDateString);
        }

            //#### 
        return dReturn;
    }
})();
```

In my actual (dotNet) code, I'm collecting the a_sLanguage array via:

```
a_sLanguage = '<% Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]); %>'.split(',');
```

Now, I'm not certain my approach to locating "us-en"/etc. is the most proper. Pretty much it's just the US and current/former US influenced areas (Palau, Micronesia, Philippines) + Belize & Canada that use the funky MM/DD/YYYY format (I am American, so I can call it funky =). So one could rightly argue that if the Locale is not "en-us"/etc. first, then DD/MM/YYYY should be used. Thoughts?

As a side note... I "grew up" in PERL but it's been a wee while since I've done much heavy lifting in RegEx. Does that expression look right to everyone?

This seems like a lot of work, but based on my research this is indeed about the best way to go about enabling DD/MM/YYYY dates within JavaScript. Is there an easier/more betterer way?

*PS- Upon re-reading this post just before submission... I've realized that this is more of a "can you code review this" rather then a question (or, an answer is embedded within the question). When I started writing this it was not my intention to end up here =)*

Comment: Used this code for a jQuery calendar plugin. Thanks for sharing! You can check it out here: https://github.com/joelalejandro/jquery-ja/wiki/ja.Calendar

Answer (score 5):

I would use [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/).  You can directly load the version appropriate for a given ISO language code (e.g. date-en-CA.js or date-en-GB.js).  Only the capitalization is different.

Comment: I looked at this one this afternoon, but it seemed a bit heavier weight then I was looking for. Plus I wasn't convinced by the documentation that it's Date.parse was any different then the in-built version (as it's CulturalInfo page is just a stub). It sorta looked to me it was using .parseExact to accomplish DD/MM/YYYY (but I am most likely wrong on that point).

Am I correct in assuming that Datejs replaces/overrides the inbuilt JavaScript Date object?

Comment: Also re: Datejs... Despite my example above (which was simplified and made to modify Date.parse itself), in my JavaScripting I always strive to only create 1 variable and otherwise leave the JavaScript namespace untouched (I learned this thanks to YUI). So I create a single base object and attach all of my functions/objects/etc. under it. I do this so that my code (save that 1 variable name) will cause no conflicts/collisions with any other JavaScript on the page. Basically I shun "prototype" =) Anyway... it looks like Datejs not only tweaks the Date object, but integers as well.