# how to parse a "dd/mm/yyyy" or "dd-mm-yyyy" or "dd-mmm-yyyy" formatted date string using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extending JavaScript's Date.parse to allow for DD/MM/YYYY (non-US formatted dates)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003355/extending-javascripts-date-parse-to-allow-for-dd-mm-yyyy-non-us-formatted-date)
>   [Convert dd-mm-yyyy string to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151543/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-to-date)

Entered a date in textbox, for example: *05/09/1985*, and I wanted to convert it to *05-Sep-1985* (dd-MMM-yyyy) format. How would I achieve this? Note that the source format may be `dd-mm-yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy` or `dd-mmm-yyyy` format.

**Code Snippet:**

```
 function GetDateFormat(controlName) {
        if ($('#' + controlName).val() != "") {      
            var d1 = Date.parse($('#' + controlName).val());
            if (d1 == null) {
                alert('Date Invalid.');
                $('#' + controlName).val("");
            }
                var array = d1.toString('dd-MMM-yyyy');
                $('#' + controlName).val(array);
        }
    }
```

This code returns *09-May-1985* but I want *05-Sep-1985*. Thanks.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You might want to use helper library like http://momentjs.com/ which wraps the native javascript date object for easier manipulations

Then you can do things like:

```
var day = moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");
```

or

```
var day = moment("25/12/1995", "DD/MM/YYYY");
```

then operate on the date

```
day.add('days', 7)
```

and to get the native javascript date

```
day.toDate();
```

Comment: Can't use moment due to security issues in my project. I think splitting is the only choice for me.

Answer (score 78):

**Update**

Below you've said:

> Sorry, i can't predict date format before, it should be like dd-mm-yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy or dd-mmm-yyyy format finally i wanted to convert all this format to dd-MMM-yyyy format.

That ***completely*** changes the question. It'll be much more complex if you can't control the format. There is nothing built into JavaScript that will let you specify a date format. Officially, the only date format supported by JavaScript is a [simplified version of ISO-8601](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.15): `yyyy-mm-dd`, although in practice almost all browsers also support `yyyy/mm/dd` as well. But other than that, you have to write the code yourself or (and this makes much more sense) use a good library. I'd probably use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) or [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) (although DateJS hasn't been maintained in years).

---

**Original answer**:

If the format is *always* `dd/mm/yyyy`, then this is trivial:

```
var parts = str.split("/");
var dt = new Date(parseInt(parts[2], 10),
                  parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1,
                  parseInt(parts[0], 10));
```

`split` splits a string on the given delimiter. Then we use `parseInt` to convert the strings into numbers, and we use the `new Date` constructor to build a `Date` from those parts: The third part will be the year, the second part the month, and the first part the day. `Date` uses zero-based month numbers, and so we have to subtract one from the month number.

Comment: Sorry, i can't predict date format before, it should be like dd-mm-yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy or dd-mmm-yyyy format finally i wanted to convert all this format to dd-MMM-yyyy format.

Comment: @SharanammaJekeen: That **completely** changes the question. See update.

Comment: i will fix my source format to dd/mm/yyyy format.

Answer (score 17):

[`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) recognizes only specific formats, and you don't have the option of telling it what your input format is. In this case it thinks that the input is in the format `mm/dd/yyyy`, so the result is wrong.

To fix this, you need either to parse the input yourself (e.g. with [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)) and then [manually construct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/constructor) a `Date` object, or use a more full-featured library such as [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/).

Example for manual parsing:

```
var input = $('#' + controlName).val();
var parts = str.split("/");
var d1 = new Date(Number(parts[2]), Number(parts[1]) - 1, Number(parts[0]));
```

Example using date.js:

```
var input = $('#' + controlName).val();
var d1 = Date.parseExact(input, "d/M/yyyy");
```

Comment: then how can i achieve above format?

Comment: @SharanammaJekeen: I 'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: it might be also easier to reconstruct the date by concatenating in `mm/dd/yyyy` format with `new Date(\`${parts[1]}/${parts[0]}/${parts[2]}\`)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 function GetDateFormat(controlName) {
        if ($('#' + controlName).val() != "") {      
            var d1 = Date.parse($('#' + controlName).val().toString().replace(/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)/,'$2/$1'));
            if (d1 == null) {
                alert('Date Invalid.');
                $('#' + controlName).val("");
            }
                var array = d1.toString('dd-MMM-yyyy');
                $('#' + controlName).val(array);
        }
    }
```

The RegExp replace `.replace(/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)/,'$2/$1')` change day/month position.

Comment: Nice usage of `RegEx`.

Answer (score -7):

See this http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

you can do anything with date.

file : http://stevenlevithan.com/assets/misc/date.format.js

add this to your html code using script tag and to use you can use it as :

```
var now = new Date();

now.format("m/dd/yy");
// Returns, e.g., 6/09/07
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Please add the comment for - vote so that atleast I can know my mistake

Comment: I guess, it was because the OP asked how to PARSE a date passed in, into  the form 'dd/mm/yyyy' and your response seems to be about how you format the current date - maybe ?

Comment: Nice... if the point you mentioned is the reason for the down vote...I gave generic date conversion so that it would be easy to understand. Ok, will keep these things in mind before giving answers. Thanks for the info.