# How to convert "DD-MMM-YYYY" string to date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

How to convert a "DD-MMM-YYYY" string to a date in Jquery?

I've a date in string "14-Jun-2014". I want to convert it to a date; something like this `14-06-2014`. For `$("#InvoiceToDate").text();` I get this `"14-Jun-2014"`

So for

```
new Date($("#InvoiceToDate").text())
```

But its showing

```
Sat Jun 14 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)
```

I've also tried this

```
new Date($("#InvoiceToDate").text()).toLocaleString('en-GB');
```

Now its showing almost what I wanted.

```
"06/08/2014 00:00:00"
```

How can I get only dd/MM/yyyy. Please help.

Comment: I've tried this >> new Date($("#InvoiceToDate").text())

But its showing >> Sat Jun 14 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)

Comment: try like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532270/date-format-conversion-from-dd-mmm-yyyy-to-dd-mm-yyyy-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had similar kind of problem. This works for me.

```
var now = new Date("14-Jun-2014");
now.toLocaleDateString("en-GB");
```

This returns "14/06/2014" in Chrome.

UPDATE:

FF and IE wouldn't swallow "14-Jun-2014". However, if you could remove the dashes from the string and replace with spaces like "14 Jun 2014" then it will work on both browsers.

```
var now = new Date("14 Jun 2014");
now.toLocaleDateString("en-GB");
```

See if this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
var fecha = "14-Jun-2014";
var myDate = new Date(fecha);
console.log(myDate);
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/pS8tc/1/

Comment: This will not work in all browsers. [Date() requires](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) a properly formatted date string, which "14-Jun-2014" isn't.

Comment: It works with Chrome, but not with Firefox. They have different implementations of Date.parse()