# Find difference between two dates with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datejs

I am trying to find the difference between two dates. The dates are got with jquery and I am using datejs too. When using datejs it picks up my date as US thinking it is MM/DD/YYYY instead of dd-mm-yyyy. My result for difference is NaN. How do I work this out. Am I miles out or anywhere near close?

```
var msMinute = 60*1000, 
    msDay = 60*60*24*1000;

start = $('#reconcile_start_date').val();   // 10-12-2014 | dd-mm-yyyy
end = $('#reconcile_end_date').val();           // 15-12-2014 | dd-mm-yyyy

start = new Date(start);
end   = new Date(end);

console.log(Math.floor((end - start) / msDay) + ' full days between ' + end + ' and ' + start);
difference = Math.floor((end - start) / msDay);

if(difference > 30){}
```

Comment: This library can be pretty helpful: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: I think its more to do with how I am using datejs. It doesnt like new Date('10-12-2014) for some reason. Is there a way to format that? I can't see (or maybe I missed it) in the documentation

Comment: If you pass the parameters to the `Date` constructor one by one (year, month, day) you'll get what you're expecting. Don't pass it as a string.

Comment: Using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) is probably the easiest way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var msMinute = 60*1000; 
    var msDay = 60*60*24*1000;

    var start = '10-12-2014'; // October 12
    var statarr=start.split('-');

    var end = '12-15-2014'; // December 15
    var endarr=end.split('-');

    var dstart = new Date(statarr[0]+'/'+statarr[1]+'/'+statarr[2]).getTime();
    var dend   = new Date(endarr[0]+'/'+endarr[1]+'/'+endarr[2]).getTime();

    var diff = parseInt(dend-dstart);

    console.log(Math.floor(diff / msDay) + ' full days between ' + end + ' and ' + start);
    difference = Math.floor((end - start) / msDay);

    if(difference > 30){
    }
    });
```

**// for UK formate use this:**

```
var start = '12-10-2014'; // October 12
    var statarr=start.split('-');

    var end = '15-12-2014'; // December 15
    var endarr=end.split('-');

    var dstart = new Date(statarr[1]+'/'+statarr[0]+'/'+statarr[2]).getTime();
    var dend   = new Date(endarr[1]+'/'+endarr[0]+'/'+endarr[2]).getTime();
```

and rest is same.

Comment: Can you get this working for UK date. So start = 12-10-2014 -> 12th October 2014

Comment: you mean by 12th October 2014 or 12-10-2014.

Comment: Yes, sorry I figured it out afterwards, just moving the array about. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is around the parsing of the dates, by default JS wont parse the date in the format.

Some more examples on how to convert the date format from UK format can be found ([Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse))

More information of the dateString param, formats and browser behaviour - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

See this sample. http://jsbin.com/fayerihipu/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var msMinute = 60*1000, 
var msDay = 60*60*24*1000;

var start = '10-12-2014'; // October 12
var end = '12-15-2014'; // December 15

var dstart = new Date(start).getTime();
var dend   = new Date(end).getTime();

var diff = parseInt(dend-dstart);

console.log(Math.floor(diff / msDay) + ' full days between ' + end + ' and ' + start);
difference = Math.floor((end - start) / msDay);

if(difference > 30){
}
});
```

Comment: this new Date(start) will give invalid date then how you are using getTime() on it.

Comment: Check the fiddle link. The formats of the inputs has been switched to show. You need to use the conversion technique linked above to convert the date from UK format.

Comment: But this output is wrong "1156 full days between 15-12-2014 and 12-10-2014" Should only be 64 I think, but definately not 1156

Comment: @PierceMcGeough yes it will be 64.

Answer (score 0):

Officially, the only date format supported by JavaScript is a simplified version of [ISO-8601](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.1.15): `yyyy-mm-dd`, and almost all browsers also support `yyyy/mm/dd` as well.

So you need to do something like this to parse your dates:

```
var parts = start.split('-');
start = new Date(parseInt(parts[2], 10),
              parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1,
              parseInt(parts[0], 10));
//Date uses zero-based month numbers, and so we have to subtract one from the month number
```

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430321/how-to-parse-a-dd-mm-yyyy-or-dd-mm-yyyy-or-dd-mmm-yyyy-formatted-date-string) for more details.