# JavaScript Date (and Date Time) validation using format parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, date, datetime

I found many custom format validation questions and answers, however all's format was a specific hardcoded format. I would like to allow to set date and datetime format as (runtime) "setting" in my web application so it will dynamic at runtime. I would like to validate the user input against this setting:

```
isValidDate(userInput, currentSetting)
```

the content for currentSetting variable could be for example: `mm/dd/yyyy`

or `yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss` (for date time)

I do not want reinvent the wheel, but I did not found such an universal parse/validate method. Missed I something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10431505/2905135

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use momentjs. it provides all kind of time/date related functions

http://momentjs.com/