# Function getUTCDate() returns a month

Tags: javascript, getdate

I have the code (19 is the day, 6 is the month)

```
var dateObj = new Date("19.6.2018");
var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

newdate =  day + '.' + month + '.' + year;
alert(newdate);
```

This code returns NaN.NaN.NaN

Function getUTCDate() returns a month. I do not know why.

I'm Slovak. The first number is the day. The second number is a month.

Comment: `dateObj` is invalid date

Comment: I'm Slovak. The first number is the day. The second number is a month.
I do not know how to exchange a day with a month

Comment: `dateObj` would be null. check it with `console.log(dateObj)` etc

Comment: var dateObj = new Date("6/19/2018");

Comment: Nope, the above could also be fine, if he enters the month before day.

Comment: How to exchange a day with a month? 
Date I get from input where is the first day

Comment: Why not you use `new Date(year, month, day)`. Doc : [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp). But these will in `int` not `String`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to parse a "dd/mm/yyyy" or "dd-mm-yyyy" or "dd-mmm-yyyy" formatted date string using JavaScript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430321/how-to-parse-a-dd-mm-yyyy-or-dd-mm-yyyy-or-dd-mmm-yyyy-formatted-date-stri)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dateString argument to [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) must be in a format recognised by `Date.parse()`

> String value representing a date. The string should be in a format
>   recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822
>   timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).

The date time string may be in a simplified ISO 8601 format. For example, "2011-10-10"

In your case it can be

```js
var dateObj = new Date("2018-06-19");
var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

newdate =  day + '.' + month + '.' + year;
console.log(newdate);
```

You can take you string and format it properly like

```js
const str = "19.6.2018"
const arr = str.split('.');
const newString = `${arr[1]}-${arr[0]}-${arr[2]}`;
console.log(newString)
var dateObj = new Date(newString);
console.log(dateObj)
    var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
    var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
    var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

    newdate =  day + '.' + month + '.' + year;
    alert(newdate);
```

Comment: Date I get from input where is the first day!

Comment: updated my answer on how to format your string input

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Shubham Khatri answer, here's how you can convert your input to the correct format:

```js
const getUTCDate = (year, month, day ) => {
  const date = new Date(`${year}-${month}-${day}`);
  const m = date.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
  const d = date.getUTCDate();
  const y = date.getUTCFullYear();

  return [m, d, y]
}

const input = '19.6.2018'
const date = input.split('.')
// Here we convert your input, in the correct order `getUTCDate` expected
const result = getUTCDate(date[2], date[1], date[0])
console.log(result)
```