# how do i loop through input data?

Tags: javascript, loops

So I need to create three input fields with one button. One input field for a date, one for an amount of money and one for an interest rate. When clicking on the button an overview of the sum must be displayed over the course of the next years until its doubled using the given interest rate.

My question is how can I loop through these years until the sum is doubled. The rest of the code I have and works.

I'm new to javascript and coding and would appreciate anyones help.

This is the code I have right now:

```
s = sum
d = date
r = interest rate

for (var i = 0; i < s; i++) {
   result.innerHTML += d + " " + ((r / 100 + 1) * s) + "<br>";
}
```

The complete code : https://jsfiddle.net/swateen/bjah4rc0/

Comment: Not sure what is Sum here? And also what do you want? You want to show the amount (with interest) from the given date to till the date?

Comment: i should have made that more clear:

sum is the amount of money from the second input field. 
I want to show the amount (with interest) for each year until the amount is doubled.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could [edit] your question to include actual code (HTML & JavaScript) that you've built so far, that's relevant to the question you have. See [mcve] for information on how to do that. You can use Stack Snippets (the icon is `<>` in the editor toolbar) to help construct the code.

Comment: thanks for the tip. the complete code can be found here : https://jsfiddle.net/swateen/bjah4rc0/

Comment: the reason for down voting is that this problem is not about javascript or loops or any other thing. its just about programming logic. i would though, post the solution but since there is already one, i think you dont need anymore answers. happy coding mate.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying Wahid! Next time I will make sure to categorize it correctly. You too!

Answer (score 0):

```
function loop() {
    var d = new Date(inputA.value);
    var s = inputB.value;
    var r = inputC.value;
    var doubleS = s * 2;

    while(s < doubleS)
        d = new Date(d.getFullYear() + 1, d.getMonth(), d.getDate());
        s = ((r / 100 + 1) * s);
        result.innerHTML += d + " " + s + "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! One minor problem, instead of giving the date it gives "Invalid date"

Comment: Date expects format "dd/mm/yyyy". Read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430321/how-to-parse-a-dd-mm-yyyy-or-dd-mm-yyyy-or-dd-mmm-yyyy-formatted-date-stri to see different ways to parse other formats.

Comment: Thanks for the help!