# Is it possible to send a different value than what's displayed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, thymeleaf

I am trying to send back a date that the user put into the format `dd/MM/yyyy`. However, since my back end is in Java, when I create the object in the page (via Thymeleaf) where the date format is `MM/dd/yyyy`, it messes up the date.

```
<form th:action="@{/addDate}" th:object="${date}" method="POST" class="bd-example">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dateInput" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" th:field="*{date}" required />
```

Is there any way to change this value in the page without modifying the method of the object in the back end?

Comment: Parse the date to a different format in JS, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430321/how-to-parse-a-dd-mm-yyyy-or-dd-mm-yyyy-or-dd-mmm-yyyy-formatted-date-stri

Comment: Have a hidden field which holds the value you want to use in the backend. Failing that, it shouldn't be hard to parse a different date format in Java.

Comment: Use fake input for user and move value with proper format to actual hidden field using JS

Comment: how is it possible to do that?

Comment: @shas whenever the user types something (you can detect it with keyup, or if you prefer, you can wait until the finished typing and the control loses focus), run a JS function which copies the current content of the textbox to the hidden field, and transforms it along the way (for that you can use JavaScript date functions, or a library like momentJS, or just do some simple string manipulation).

Comment: i use a jquerry datepicker, does it change anything?

Comment: it shouldn't no. Why not try it and see?

Comment: Did you managed to solve it? I had use datepicker before and I know getting it's value it quite tricky.

Comment: im still working on it, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151543/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-to-date seems to work for  datepicker, so im trying it.