# change default date format to d/m/Y in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to calculate the date range using date format d/m/y using javascript. 
example: 20/1/2020 until 21/1/2020 is a 1-day difference.

[select 8th January 2020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7RRg.png)

but when I console it shows as "Sat Aug 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)" and if I pick 13/01/2020 its will come out as an invalid date.

How can I change the date format from m/d/Y to d/m/Y because this will affect my calculation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How does that affect your calculation? The way you pass the parameters in shouldn't affect anything.

Comment: @user1538301, for example when I select 9/1/2020 and 8/1/2020 it will calculate as 30days difference.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10430376/906113

Answer (score 0):

If you direly need to pass the date in as 'd/m/y' you can just write a factory function for Dates:

```js
var getDate = function(dateString) { 
   var dateParts = dateString.split('/');
   var datePartsTmp = dateString.split('/');
   dateParts[0] = datePartsTmp[1];
   dateParts[1] = datePartsTmp[0];
   return dateParts.join('/');
};
console.log(getDate('13/01/2020'));
```