How to pass $DATE$ from HTML to JavaScript
I try to write a function that translates a date in English into long date in Polish.
The code looks as follows:
Html part:
<div class="blogitem">
   <$HEADING$ class="blogsubject">$SUBJECT$</$HEADING$>
   <p class="blogdate">
      <script type="text/javascript">document.write(date2polish($DATE$))</script>
   </p>
   <p class="blogthumb">$IMAGE$</p>
   $TEXT$
   <a class="blogbutton" href="$URL$" target="$TARGET$">$BUTTONTEXT$</a>
   <p><span class="blogcomments">$LABEL$ <a style="color: black;" href="mailto:$EMAIL$?subject=$SUBJECT$">$EMAIL$</a></span> </p>
</div>

and JS part:
DayT = new Array(7) 
DayT[0] = "niedziela" 
DayT[1] = "poniedziałek" 
DayT[2] = "wtorek" 
DayT[3] = "środa" 
DayT[4] = "czwartek" 
DayT[5] = "piątek" 
DayT[6] = "sobota"

MonthT = new Array(12) 
MonthT[0] = "stycznia" 
MonthT[1] = "lutego" 
MonthT[2] = "marca" 
MonthT[3] = "kwietnia" 
MonthT[4] = "maja" 
MonthT[5] = "czerwca" 
MonthT[6] = "lipca" 
MonthT[7] = "sierpnia" 
MonthT[8] = "września" 
MonthT[9] = "października" 
MonthT[10] = "listopada" 
MonthT[11] = "grudnia"

function date2polish(dateT){

    console.log("dateT = " , dateT);
    
    const tEMP = new Date(dateT);

    var Day = tEMP.getDate();
    var DayOW = tEMP.getDay();
    var Month = tEMP.getMonth(); 
    var Year = tEMP.getFullYear();
    
    return DayT[DayOW] + " , " + Day + " " + MonthT[Month] + " , " + Year;
}

I get the following result in console:
dateT =  0.0000823451910408432 
dateT =  0.00009881422924901186 
dateT =  0.0001646903820816864 
dateT =  0.0004940711462450593

As I understand 4 dates that are given like 01/01/2024, 01/03/2024, 01/05/2024 and 01/06/2024 are coded in some format that is not understood by js or am I wrong?
Could you please advise where I do the mistake?

What is all the $XXX$ stuff in your HTML? Are you using some kind of templating system to replace them with values?

If $DATE$ is replaced with a string, you need to put it in quotes. So it should be document.write(date2polish('$DATE$'))

Yes, this is part of web editor and I try to customize one of the layouts.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430321/how-to-parse-a-dd-mm-yyyy-or-dd-mm-yyyy-or-dd-mmm-yyyy-formatted-date-stri regarding parsing date strings like this.

Yes... lack of quotes was the issue... Thanks!
