# Convert Date to DDMMYYYY from any other formats

Tags: javascript

Convert Date to DDMMYYYY from any other formats

```
var date = new Date("2019/12/27"),
yr = date.getFullYear(),
month = date.getMonth() < 10 ? '0' + date.getMonth() : date.getMonth(),
day = date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + date.getDate() : date.getDate(),
newDate = yr + '-' + month + '-' + day;
```

I tried like this 
but it is not accepting '27/12/2019'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extending JavaScript's Date.parse to allow for DD/MM/YYYY (non-US formatted dates)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003355/extending-javascripts-date-parse-to-allow-for-dd-mm-yyyy-non-us-formatted-date)

Comment: There is no way to do that from "any other format". You would need to specify the supported formats.

Comment: `new Date(Date.parse("2019/12/27"))`?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Moment.js library http://momentjs.com/ It will save you a LOT of trouble.

```
moment().format('DDMMMYYYY');
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Split date string

```js
var dateArr = String('27/12/2019').split('/');
var date = new Date (dateArr[2], dateArr[1] - 1, dateArr[0]);
```

this is a part from another answer [Convert dd-mm-yyyy string to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151543/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-to-date/7151626)